# Error message thinks my object is static.- Android

Tags: android, static

I'm getting an error message saying "cannot make a static reference to a non-static method" when i pass an instance to my method. It's an instance of a non-static class.

Class of the instance to pass:

```
package com.btf271.dbmodel;

public class AppUser {
    private String imagePath;

    public AppUser(){
        //default constructor
    }

    public AppUser(String imagePath){
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }

    public String getImagePath() {
        return this.imagePath;
    }
}
```

Passing it:

```
private void insertUserToDB(){
        AppUser user1 = new AppUser(mProfilePicPath);
        long user1_id = dbhelper.createAppUserSQLiteEntry(user1); //error at this line
    }
```

Comment: The error is referencing the method `createAppUserSQLiteEntry()`, not the object you are passing in to that method. What does your definition for that method look like?

Comment: Is `dbhelper` the name of a class or an object instance?

Comment: dbhelper is class name not variable.

Comment: Thanks for those questions about what dbhelper is. That is the class. dbHelper is the instance. Must change the class name to have a capital. My silly error.